# try.c:8: error: incompatible types in initialization - c

Tags: c, types, initialization

i am trying to build a simple c that reads a file and enters in into a string,
but i am getting this error while compiling:

```
try.c:8: error: incompatible types in initialization
```

this is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *try = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\try1.txt", "r");

    char *string = *try;

    printf("%s\n", string);
    printf("%s\n", try);


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

how can i fix this? thanks

Comment: The type of `*try` is `FILE`, not `char *`, of course.  You want `fread()` or `fgets()` or something.

Comment: `char *string = NULL; size_t bufsize = 0; ssize_t slen = getline(&string, &bufsize, try);`

Comment: Try using a function such as `fgets` or `fscanf` .

Comment: @EOF: `getline` is not standard. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @Olaf: `getline()` is POSIX. If you don't have `getline()`, I'm terribly sorry for you.

Comment: @EOF. No reason to become personal! The question does not mention OP uses POSIX, it does not have a POSIX tag. But it does have a C tag, so why not stick to the C standard. Even more, as that already provides a function to read a line.

Answer (score 0):

regarding this line:

```
char *string = *try;
```

the problem is the posted code is trying assign a pointer to a FILE struct to a char pointer.

In general, the value returned from `fopen()` is only good for a parameter in functions like read(), write(), fclose() fprintf() fwrite(), fread(), fscanf(), the actual contents of the FILE pointer are meaningless unless writing VERY low level code working with device drivers, etc

The posted code is trying to print the contents of `try` using a '%s' format specifier.  That will not work.  Suggest:

```
printf( "%p is where 'try' points\n", try );
```

as '%p' is used for printing addresses.

The contents of where `try` points require using the fields from the FILE struct, perhaps printing those fields one by one